# Limit width of a table within an element with display:table

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is set to `display:table` in CSS. When I place an actual `table` inside this, which I want to scroll horizontally, the outer div breaks out of the `container` and extends to page width. Can anyone help me fix this?

I'm trying to keep the container to a fixed width, no-scroll. I want just the div holding the table to scroll.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/c0996dqe/

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:500px;
}
.answer{
    display: table;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.answer:before{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 5%;
    content: "A";
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.scorestable{
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.scorestable td{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these styles to `.answer`:

```
.answer {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n47qao4g/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.scorestable{
    width:500px;
}

.container{
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned - I'm trying to keep the container to a fixed width no-scroll. I want just the div holding the HTML table to scroll.

Comment: This works but this will require me to change the width for every other device. Is this my best bet?

Comment: You can always convert the width in pixels to percentages - then you won't have to write a media query for each device.  Pixel width percentage = desired pixel width/total pixel width of parent element

Comment: I guess you have to set width to .scorestable. You could use inherit.
.answer{width:inherit;} .scorestable{width:inherit;}

Comment: no problem, i am just trying to learn myself by helping others